# How to call substring()?

Tags: freepascal

I want to write a method:

```pascal
Function TChunk.Chunk(Constref input: String; location: TLocation): String;
Begin
  Result := input.Substring(location.FStart, location.GetLen);
End;
```

but I get `Error: Illegal qualified`. The goal is to return a sub-string from `input` by a range (the `location` defines the range) - super simple kid's task. I cannot:

1. find the required string method
2. to understand how to call string's helper method - `Substring()`
3. to understand how to do this simple task in FreePascal

My strings are unicode strings actually (i am not sure in the right terminology here, but they are not ASCII (`Delphi Unicode (-MDelphiUnicode)`).

Any help for a Pascal newbie, please :)

EDIT: screenshot
[image]

EDIT: the origin of this method
[image]

Comment: Is that really the exact error message? Illegal qualified makes no sense. Is it illegal qualifier? Shouldn't this be const rather than constref? Which exact point in the code does the error occur at?

Comment: yes, I added screenshot. Exactly this error message. I am on 2.2.2 version

Comment: I don't believe that there is an error message named illegal qualified but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [copy](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/copy.html).

instead of:

```
Result := input.Substring(location.FStart, location.GetLen);
```

use:

```
Result := copy(input,location.FStart,location.GetLen);
```

Comment: `Copy()` is compiled. But could you explain, what is the problem exactly with `Substring()`?

Comment: there is no Substring method, unless i am missing something. please point me to some documentation about substring. unless you want to code a substring method?

Comment: I found it in the "rtl" CHM file. Its prototype is `Function Substring(AStartIndex: SizeInt; ALen: SizeInt): string; overload;` and it's defined in `syshelph.inc`, I added a new screenshot.

Comment: I see it here https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/tstringhelper.substring.html Error is illegal qualifier ? you typed qualified.

Comment: maybe to use it, some `uses ...` is required.... no idea TBH

Answer (score 1):

(you solved it another way, but to find out what went wrong)

To use an helper, you must have the corresponding unit (sysutils) in your USES list.  You can see that name top-left in your documentation snapshot

Online documentation is for current release version, are you using the latest release, 3.2.2? (sysutils is from FPC, so the FPC version counts, not the lazaurs one)